# oldData in ArrayList implementation

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm reading [ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java/?v=source) implementation and can't understand one thing in this method:

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
        Object oldData[] = elementData;
        int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
        if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what this `oldData` array is used for:

```
Object oldData[] = elementData;
```

To me it seems like there is absolutely no sense in this local variable inside `ensureCapacity` method.

Comment: I checked oracle jdk8 and there is no `oldData`, and implementation is changed. Maybe they forgot to delete it.

Comment: @miroh. Oh, thanks! It seems like google searches lead to old implementations.

Comment: @miroh Addressed in Java 7 itself :)

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6812879#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, The line is completely redundant there and left it without refactored.

Looks like that method got addressed with [`Java 7 version`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.grow%28int%29) and the whole method got refactored the logic of increasing the backed array.

Authers created another method called `grow()` and moved the logic there from version 7.

```
public void  ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
191         int minExpand = (elementData != EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA)
192             // any size if real element table
193             ? 0
194             // larger than default for empty table. It's already supposed to be
195             // at default size.
196             : DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
197 
198         if (minCapacity > minExpand) {
199             ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
200         }
201     }
202 
203     private void  ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
204         if (elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
205             minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
206         }
207 
208         ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
209     }
210 
211     private void  ensureExplicitCapacity(int minCapacity) {
212         modCount++;
213 
214         // overflow-conscious code
215         if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
216             grow(minCapacity);
217     }

    private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    234         // overflow-conscious code
    235         int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    236         int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    237         if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
    238             newCapacity = minCapacity;
    239         if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
    240             newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    241         // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    242         elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    243     }
    244 
    245     private static int More ...hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    246         if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
    247             throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    248         return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
    249             Integer.MAX_VALUE :
    250             MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
    251     }
```

Comment: That is correct - I deleted my (wrong) answer... I didn't read the code carefully...